# Multiple conditions for "walrus operator" assignment

Tags: python, python-3.8, python-assignment-expression

I'd like to know if it's possible to use the "walrus operator" to assign the value based on some condition as well as existing. For example, assign the string to `post_url` if that string contains some substring:

```
if post_url := data.get("Post url") and ("youtube" in data.get("Post url")):
    # Do something with post_url
else:
    # Do something else
```

However, this is just assigning the boolean value to `post_url` due to the evaluation of the `and` operation.

Comment: Use parentheses for the grouping you want - `post_url := (...)`. Alternatively `"youtube" in data.get("Post url", [])` would factor out the `and`.

Comment: @jonrsharpe thanks for the comment. I tried if post_url := "youtube" in data.get("Post url", []) which still returns the boolean as does if post_url := (data.get("Post url") and "youtube" in data.get("Post url")):

Comment: Oh, so you want `if (post_url := data.get("Post url")) and "youtube" in post_url:`? You don't need to double up the `.get`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use parentheses to group this how you want, you don't even need to repeat the `data.get`:

```
if (post_url := data.get("Post url")) and "youtube" in post_url:
    # Do something with post_url
else:
    # Do something else
```

This will assign a value to `post_url` either way, so you can access `None` or the URL not containing `"youtube"` in the `else` block.